# Terraform creating a new Route53 domain while the domain exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, dns, amazon-route53, aws-route53

Calling out the Route53 experts

I have an existing Route53 hosted zone called domain.ml and has a hosted zone id of ZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxX6I

Given the below terraform plan output snippet, will this change cause any problems to the existing DNS zone and records, or will it just create new records?

## Plan output

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_route53_record.ns will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "ns" {
      + allow_overwrite = (known after apply)
      + fqdn            = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = "domain-blue-green-eks.domain.ml"
      + records         = (known after apply)
      + ttl             = 30
      + type            = "NS"
      + zone_id         = " ZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxX6I"
    }

  # aws_route53_zone.sub will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_zone" "sub" {
      + arn                 = (known after apply)
      + comment             = "Managed by Terraform"
      + force_destroy       = false
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + name                = "domain-blue-green-eks.domain.ml"
      + name_servers        = (known after apply)
      + primary_name_server = (known after apply)
      + tags_all            = (known after apply)
      + zone_id             = (known after apply)
    }
```

## Code Snippet that generates this plan

```
provider "aws" {
  region = local.region
}

locals {
  name   = var.environment_name
  region = var.aws_region

  vpc_cidr       = var.vpc_cidr
  num_of_subnets = min(length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names), 3)
  azs            = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, local.num_of_subnets)

  argocd_secret_manager_name = var.argocd_secret_manager_name_suffix

  hosted_zone_name = var.hosted_zone_name

  tags = {
    Blueprint  = local.name
    GithubRepo = "github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints"
  }
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 5.0"

  name = local.name
  cidr = local.vpc_cidr

  azs             = local.azs
  public_subnets  = [for k, v in local.azs : cidrsubnet(local.vpc_cidr, 6, k)]
  private_subnets = [for k, v in local.azs : cidrsubnet(local.vpc_cidr, 6, k + 10)]

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  single_nat_gateway = true

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb" = 1
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb" = 1
  }

  tags = local.tags
}

# Retrieve existing root hosted zone
data "aws_route53_zone" "root" {
  name = local.hosted_zone_name
}

# Create Sub HostedZone for our deployment
resource "aws_route53_zone" "sub" {
  name = "${local.name}.${local.hosted_zone_name}"
}

# Validate records for the new HostedZone
resource "aws_route53_record" "ns" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.root.zone_id
  name    = "${local.name}.${local.hosted_zone_name}"
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = "30"
  records = aws_route53_zone.sub.name_servers
}

module "acm" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/acm/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"

  domain_name = "${local.name}.${local.hosted_zone_name}"
  zone_id     = aws_route53_zone.sub.zone_id

  subject_alternative_names = [
    "*.${local.name}.${local.hosted_zone_name}"
  ]

  wait_for_validation = true

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.name}.${local.hosted_zone_name}"
  }
}
```

The situation here is that I want to add these records to my existing, hosted zone which I see that the module is using, but to me the code seems to be put in a way that it is supposed to create a new sub-hosted zone and I'm not quite sure what will the implications on the existing records be.

I was considering the below solution as in to use the existing hosted zone.

[AWS - Route53 - Terraform - Update domain nameservers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75931536/aws-route53-terraform-update-domain-nameservers)

I tried running a speculative plan in terraform.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import) your existing Route64 Hosted Zone into terraform. TF docs for `aws_route53_zone` [show example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_zone#import) of how to do it:

```
terraform import aws_route53_zone.root Z1D633PJN98FT9
```

You have to do it for all pre-existing resources that you want to control from TF. Otherwise you will get error that a given resource already exists as TF will try to create it.

Comment: They are creating a new Route53 hosted zone for a subdomain of the root domain. I don't think they need to import the root, just use the datasource like they are doing already.

Comment: The confusing part is that it creates a new NS record while using the zone_id of the existing hosted zone.

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform code in the question is creating an entirely new Route53 hosted zone for a subdomain of your root domain, and creating a new `NS` record in the root hosted zone to delegate management of that subdomain to the newly Route53 hosted zone.

---

> The situation here is that I want to add these records to my existing, hosted zone

Then you shouldn't be writing code that creates an entirely new hosted zone. You should just be creating records in the existing hosted zone.

Comment: The code is based on the example given in the AWS EKS blueprints for the [EKS Blue/Green example](https://github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints/tree/main/patterns/blue-green-upgrade#quick-start)

not a 100% sure why they are using this approach of creating a new subhosted zone for the subdomain even if a hosted zone exists.

what I know is that the TF code interacts with route53 to shift load between clusters for canary upgrades.

My question to you here is that in case we had this applied will it affect the existing Hosted zone records?

Comment: What existing hosted zone records? Your question is vague. It will certainly impact any existing hosted zone records **for the subdomain** because it will be changing the authoritative DNS server for that subdomain. It will not have any impact on any records that are not for that specific subdomain, since obviously the Terraform code in question is not touching any other records in the root hosted zone.

Comment: Yes, my question was more about the records for the existing hostedzone, not the new subdomain, given that the new subdomain is being created using this code. I think you answered my question, I will be testing/applying this and confirming that your answer is the right one if everything goes well.